# Как задать размер пакетов при синхронизации?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, entity-framework, синхронизация

sync framework 2.1, devart dotconnect for posgresql, entityframework

```
watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var conStringsServer = RestoratorConfiguration.GetConnectionStringsServer();
            var connectionStringLocal = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MenuEntities"].ConnectionString;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conStringsServer))
                return;

            PgSqlConnection centralConnection = new PgSqlConnection(connectionStringLocal); // Con
            PgSqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning t0;
            try
            {
                t0 = new PgSqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(centralConnection);
                t0.DeprovisionStore();
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
            }

            var scopeName = "SyncScope";

            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDescription = null;
            try
            {
                scopeDescription = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
                foreach (var dbTable in _orderedTables)
                {
                    DbSyncTableDescription tableDesc =
                        PgSqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(dbTable,
                            centralConnection);
                    scopeDescription.Tables.Add(tableDesc);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    scopeDescription = PgSqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(scopeName,
                        centralConnection);
                }
                catch (Exception ex1)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }


            SyncScopeProvisioning centralProvisioning = new PgSqlSyncScopeProvisioning(centralConnection,
                scopeDescription);

            centralProvisioning.Apply();

            //var branches = ec.Restaurants.Where(r => !r.IsMain).ToList();


            int j = 0;
            var count = 1;
            progress = progressInitialValue;
            branchDelta = (100 - progressInitialValue - count)/count;
            //foreach (var branch in branches)
            //{
                progress += 1;
                _bw.ReportProgress(progress, string.Format("Синхронизация с {0}...", conStringsServer));

                centralConnection = new PgSqlConnection(connectionStringLocal);

                PgSqlConnection branchConnection = new PgSqlConnection(conStringsServer); // Con

                PgSqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning t;
                try
                {
                    t = new PgSqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(branchConnection);
                    t.DeprovisionStore();
                }
                catch (Exception ex1)
                {
                }


                SyncScopeProvisioning branchProvisioning = new PgSqlSyncScopeProvisioning(branchConnection,
                    scopeDescription);

                branchProvisioning.Apply();

            var f1 = new PgSqlSyncProvider(scopeName, centralConnection, null, null);
            f1.SelectingChanges += f1_SelectingChanges;
            f1.BatchSpooled += f1_BatchSpooled;
            f1.BatchApplied += F1OnBatchApplied;
            f1.MemoryDataCacheSize = 200000;

            var f2 = new PgSqlSyncProvider(scopeName, branchConnection, null, null);
            f2.SelectingChanges += f1_SelectingChanges;
            f2.BatchSpooled += f1_BatchSpooled;
            f2.BatchApplied += F1OnBatchApplied;
            f2.MemoryDataCacheSize = 200000;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", f1.MemoryDataCacheSize);

                SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator
                {
                    Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload,
                    RemoteProvider = f1,
                    LocalProvider = f2
                };

                syncOrchestrator.SessionProgress += syncOrchestrator_SessionProgress;

                // from
                // to
                syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

                //t = new PgSqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(branchConnection);
                //t.DeprovisionStore();

                //ResetAllSequences(branchConnection);

                progress += branchDelta;

                if (progress >= 100)
                {
                    progress = 99;
                }
                _bw.ReportProgress(progress, string.Format("Завершена синхронизация {0}!", " с сервером"));

                watch.Stop();
```

Синхронизация работает, но при синхронизации через интернет, синхронизация проходит за час. Большой пинг с сервером. При синхронизации через локальную сеть, синхронизация проходит за 1,5 минуты. поэтому нужно уменьшить размер пакетов (batchsize)